# Single-selectable listview in pure HTML/CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-select

By default a `<select>` element is a dropdown menu which I don't want: I want to display the *full list*. This is possible with `multiple`:

```html
<select name="pets" multiple size="5">
<option>dog</option>
<option>cat</option>
<option>hamster</option>
<option>bird</option>
<option>donkey</option>
<option>fish</option>
</select>
```

but then obviously the user can select *multiple* elements.

**How to have a full list view (like with `multiple`, i.e. no dropdown menu), but have only one possible selected element?**

Comment: On my macbook on Google Chrome I am only able to select one from the list in your code snippet. But my guess is to remove the multiple attribute from the select element

Comment: @FUZIION, if you hold the shift key while clicking the options it should allow you to select multiple options

Comment: Ah yes I see now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `size` attribute which takes the number of items you want to display and set it to the number of `options` you have (6) in order to get the full list view. Since you only want to allow 1 item to be selected, also remove the attribute `multiple` from the `select` element.

```html
<select name="pets" size=6>
  <option>dog</option>
  <option>cat</option>
  <option>hamster</option>
  <option>bird</option>
  <option>donkey</option>
  <option>fish</option>
</select>
```

Check [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select) for more information about the available attributes for the `select` element.

Answer (score 2):

You can make the `<select>` 100% of the height of the `<form>` that contains it. See this fiddle for an example of a div enclosing a form, with a select filling the height of the form.

This starts with a simple structure, just enough that the form is enclosed in something so you can see the relative layout.

```
    <div>
        <form>
        <select id="thelist" name="pets" size="6">
        <option value="1">dog</option>
        <option value="2">cat</option>
        <option value="3">hamster</option>
        <option value="4">bird</option>
        <option value="5">donkey</option>
        <option value="6">fish</option>
        </select>
        </form>
    </div>
```

I give the div a height, a background so you can see it, and padding so it's content doesn't naturally cover it. Make the form any height you want, including 100% of the div. I made it 90% so you can still see the enclosing div. Notice the form's width fills the div width except for the padding.

You can then just set the height of the select list to anything you want inside the form. Here's my CSS

```
div {
    background-color: #fff0f0;
    height: 40em;
    padding: 1.5em 1.5em 0 1.5em;
}
form {
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    height: 90%;
}
#thelist {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Put together as a snippet, and making it smaller to fit better here...

```css
div {
    background-color: #fff0f0;
    height: 20em;
    padding: 1.5em 1.5em 0 1.5em;
}
form {
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    height: 40%;
}
#thelist {
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <form>
        <select id="thelist" name="pets" size="6">
            <option value="1">dog</option>
            <option value="2">cat</option>
            <option value="3">hamster</option>
            <option value="4">bird</option>
            <option value="5">donkey</option>
            <option value="6">fish</option>
        </select>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tested a few solutions and found that you had to remove the `multiple` attribute from the `<select>` element

```html
<select name="pets" size="5">
<option>dog</option>
<option>cat</option>
<option>hamster</option>
<option>bird</option>
<option>donkey</option>
<option>fish</option>
</select>
```